# Identify a unique tag using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

BeautifulSoup treats two tags as identical if they both contain the exact same content, even when the two tags are *not* the same DOM node.

Example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
x = '<div class="a"><span>hello</span></div><div class="b"><span>hello</span></div>'
page = BeautifulSoup(x, 'html.parser')

spans = page.select('span')

spans[0] == spans[1] # prints True
```

The way I have managed to get around this is to account for their parents as well, e.g.:

```
spans = page.select('span')

spans[0] == spans[1] and list(spans[0].parents) == list(spans[1].parents) # prints False
```

However, this method - when used on a normal HTML page with many nested DOM nodes - is often an order of magnitude slower than just comparing spans[0] to spans[1] without the parents.

My question is: is there a more efficient way to determine, via Beautiful Soup, whether two nodes are truly the same one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `id()`:

```py
print(id(spans[0]) == id(spans[1]))
```

Prints:

```
False
```

---

Or `is` operator:

```py
print(spans[0] is spans[1])
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you! Where is this documented btw? I don't see this in the BS documentation.

Comment: @jayp You probably don't find this in `beautifulsoup` documentation. It's standard Python feature. https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id

Comment: For anyone who might find this information useful, implementing this change resulted in more than 100x speed improvement. Game-changer.